# Handling Vert.x NetSocket writeQueueFull when using EventBus

Tags: java, sockets, vert.x

In the [*Vert.x* documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#streams), it shows a pattern for writing to sockets that are full.

```java
NetServer server = vertx.createNetServer(
    new NetServerOptions().setPort(1234).setHost("localhost")
);
server.connectHandler(sock -> {
  sock.handler(buffer -> {
    sock.write(buffer);
    if (sock.writeQueueFull()) {
      sock.pause();
      sock.drainHandler(done -> {
        sock.resume();
      });
    }
  });
}).listen();
```

How do you implement this pattern if you're writing to a socket via the *EventBus* from a different *Verticle*?

An example:

```java
vertx.eventBus().publish(writeHandlerID, buffer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Vert.x 3.5.1, backpressure is not supported on the EventBus. There are plans to implements streaming with backpressure on top of the EventBus and websockets in the next version.